GNU Radio and gr-inspector
Hello everyone! I have a problem in GNU Radio regarding the gr-inspector. I want to save the data it provides me (using a Python block) in a csv format. The actual problem is that I don't know what kind of data it has at the map_out port and what kind of input data should I make for the Python block in order to connect them.This is my python code:
from gnuradio import gr
import csv
import numpy
class MyPythonBlock(gr.sync_block):
    def __init__(self, file_path='output.csv'):  
        gr.sync_block.__init__(self,
            name="Date salvare",
            in_sig=[(numpy.float32)], 
            out_sig=None)
        self.csv_file = open(file_path, 'w', newline='')
        self.csv_writer = csv.writer(self.csv_file)
    def work(self, input_items, output_items):
        # Obține datele de la blocul Inspector Sink
        inspector_data = input_items[0]
        self.csv_writer.writerow(inspector_data)
        return gr.sync_block.consume(0)
    def stop(self):
        self.csv_file.close()
        return True 


compare: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78491896/gnu-radio-and-gr-inspector

the error display in GRC will actually tell you that you're connecting a message output port to a stream input port, and that doesn't work. So, the advice here is simple: write a block that accepts messages, and deal with the messages coming from the Inspector Sink. You can use the "message debug" block to get insight into what these messages are. Or, even easier, you just read the source code of that block – we're keeping GNU Radio free and open source for a reason.
